# Mysterious key combination changes DELETE key functionality

Tags: vim

I use <kbd>DEL</kbd> key to delete characters in NORMAL mode. However, after I randomly press some key combination the <kbd>DEL</kbd> key instead of deleting will alter a character's case - from 'a' will make 'A', from 'A' will make 'a'.

What to press to make it work as usual?

Once I restart VIM everything is ok again.

Comment: The key which normally inverts case for the character under the cursor is `~`.

Comment: In terminal, the Del key sends this sequence : `\0x21[3~`. Esc in normal mode does dothing, `[3` does nothing as well, so there is only `~` left, which inverts case.